# How to know whether turn on sync in chrome browser is enabled using javascript

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

I am trying to check below point for my assignment programatically
1. check if turn on sync is enabled in chrome

EDIT:
So far i have developed a chrome extension and trying to get the chrome.storage.sync object 
But i am unable to get the status of the turn on sync "whether synced or no"

```
Below is my manifest.json
  {
    "name": "Check Turn on sync",
    "version": "1.0",
    "description": "Build an Extension!",
    "permissions": ["storage"],
    "background": {
    "scripts": ["background.js"],
    "persistent": false
    },
   "manifest_version": 2
 }
```

I have provided a background.js file

is there a way in chrome.storage.sync that provides status of the sync

Comment: What you have tries so far?

Comment: I tried to run the below code in Javascript console :chrome.storage.sync.set({date: date}); : i get below error :Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'sync' of undefined at <anonymous>. I am not able to get any output for console.log(chrome.storage.syn)

Answer (score 0):

I am going to answer my own question, as i was able to find the answer.

I was able to get the status of sync is turned on or no along with the email ids. Here is the code :

create a manifest.json file with below content

```
  {
      "name": "Test turn on sync",
      "version": "1.0",
      "description": "Extension",
      "permissions":[
      "identity", 
      "identity.email"
      ],
      "background": {
      "scripts": ["background.js"],
      "persistent": false
   },
      "manifest_version": 2
 }
```

Create a background.js file in the same folder

```
chrome.identity.getProfileUserInfo(function(data) {
if (data.id) {
    alert(data);
}
else
{
    alert("User has not turned on sync");
}
});
```

Add the folder as chrome extension Run the extension from chrome with the help of identity.email in permissions, you will be able to get even the email-id of the user who has turned on sync, along with status.